# Get updated value of a text area - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to get the value after updating a text area in javascript?

`document.getElementById("txtArea").innerHTML` doest give the updated value.

```
<p>
    <textarea style="width:270px;height:100px" id='txtData' rows='3' cols='80'></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <button type=button style="width:270px;height:40px" onclick="getValue();" id='btnGet'>Get</button>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue () {
        alert(document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually `innerHTML` will give the value of the `textarea` as well as `value`. Are you using a library, like CodeMirror? Or is this inside a loop? I mean, how you actually use the value?

Comment: <p><textarea style="width:270px;height:100px" id='txtData' rows='3' cols='80'></textarea></p>
        <p><button type=button style="width:270px;height:40px"  onclick="getValue();"  id='btnGet'>Get</button></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            function getValue(){
                alert(document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML);
            }
       </script>

Comment: When i click on the button after editing the text area, it doesn't give the current value. Any idea on why this doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: I got it! document.getElementById("txtArea").value is the way to get that! Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("txtArea").value; //value of textarea
```

Comment: No problem @user1425267 :-D